# How to calculate the percentage of two dynamic columns values in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have two columns 2016 and 2015 representing the years from the Year column. Each of these years has values for example:

[image]

The columns(2016 , 2015) are generated dynamically. I want to calculate the percentage by taking value of 2016 and dividing it through the value of 2015. Now the question is, how can I get to the values? I tried to do it through this expression, but It is not working properly.

Expression :

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value="2016",Fields!Amount.Value,0)/
IIF(Fields!Year.Value="2015",Fields!Amount.Value,0)
```

Comment: When you say hat the columns are generated dynamically it means you have a column group aiming to the Year column? You will have only thwo possible values in the Year column?

Comment: @alejandro yes I have group aiming on the year column.

Comment: in that case you have always only two possible values in the rows of the year column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2016,Fields!Amount.Value,0))/
SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2015,Fields!Amount.Value,0))
```

**UPDATE:**

I've created a matrix to show you the required setup.

[image]

Note Prozent is outside the Year column group. It produces:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @SharmiThaya, It is possible your dataset doesn't include data for 2015 and it tried to divide by zero, or you are using the expression out of the scope of year column group. Could you add a screenshot of you matrix?

Comment: here is the screenshot of my matrix

Comment: @SharmiThaya, where are you using the expression in the matrix? Try creating a new column to the right of Year column and outside the Year group.

Comment: The dataset 2015 has values ... @alejandro

Comment: The Prozent column is a new column and that's where the expression is being used...its a column outside the group.

Comment: @SharmiThaya, check the update and try to reproduce the setup.